# Overwriting local changes in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Git in Visual Studio and am getting this error when trying to pull:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge
```

However when I try and commit it won't let me because I have to pull first, so it's a vicious cycle.

There doesn't seem to be anything much on how to fix this error from within Visual Studio.

How can I just get the latest version on the server and overwrite my local changes?

Comment: You should be able to *commit* (not push) without having to pull. Are you using VS 2013?

Comment: yes I am using VS 2013.

Comment: There are "out going commits", but when I "sync" it gives me the error.

Comment: Make sure you have upgraded to VS 2013 Update 4.  There are bugs in prior versions in identifying dirty files in your working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I just get the latest version on the server and overwrite my local changes?

In the *Team Explorer* window, in the list of pending changes (that’s also where you create commits), you can right click on files and then click “Undo…” to undo whatever local changes you did to those files. Then you should be able to pull.

However, you shouldn’t need to pull just to commit. Git commits to your local repository, the state of other remote repository is never considered for commits.

> There are "out going commits", but when I "sync" it gives me the error.

The “Sync” button in the *“Unsyched Commits”* view will push and pull. This indeed requires you not to have uncommitted changes (that could be overwritten) in your working directory. Go into the “Changes” view and make a commit first if you want to keep the changes; or undo them as explained above.

Comment: There are no files listed in the changes view.

Comment: Then the changes you are pulling includes a (new) file that wasn’t previously part of the repository but which *does exist* in your file system.

Comment: All I want to do is have the exact copy of what the server has.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave I'm facing the same issue, no files in changes tab, any steps to resolve this?

Comment: Can't remember but I think the best thing to do is learn git properly which I hadn't done and use a visual aide like SourceTree. You can always reclone the repository